# Interrupting a BlockingQueue in a Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

I'm writing a program that has 3 threads. One reads a text file and inputs the words into a ArraylistBlockingQueue of size 2. The next one takes that list and reverses every other word inside of it. The last thread takes the words and writes them to a new text file.

I have everything working except I cannot figure out how to interrupt and stop my threads. The program writes the text file but never ends.

Main method

```
 JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    File selectedFile = null;
    File outFile = new File("output.txt");

    int returnValue = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();

    }




    BlockingQueue text = new ArrayBlockingQueue(2);
    BlockingQueue out = new ArrayBlockingQueue(2);

    Thread input = new Thread(new inputClass(selectedFile, text));
    Thread reverse = new Thread(new reverseClass(text, out));
    Thread output = new Thread(new outputClass(out, outFile));


    chooser.setSelectedFile(outFile);
    if (chooser.showSaveDialog(chooser) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

        input.start();
        reverse.start();
        output.start();


    }
```

Input

```
@Override
public void run() {

    try {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(f);

        while (isRunning) {

            try {
                if(s.hasNext()){
                text.put(s.next());
                } else {
               text.put(END);
            }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

                Logger.getLogger(inputClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } 

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(inputClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Reverse Class
    @Override
    public void run() {

```
    String original;
    String temp = "";
    String character = "";
    int count = 1; // keeps track of whether or not a word should be reversed

    while (isRunning) {

        try {

            original = text.take();
            if(original.equalsIgnoreCase(END)){
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            int length = original.length() - 1;
            //if count is even then the word should be reversed.
            if ((count % 2) == 0) {
                // reverses the original string if a ? or . appears
                if (original.contains("?") || original.contains(".")) {
                    character = original.charAt(length) + "";
                    for (int i = (length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
                        temp = temp + original.charAt(i);

                    }
                    out.put(temp + character);
                    temp = "";
                    character = "";
                    // reverses the orgininal string if no ? or . appears
                } else {

                    for (int i = length; i >= 0; i--) {
                        temp = temp + original.charAt(i);

                    }
                    out.put(temp);
                    temp = "";
                }
                count++;
            } else {
                out.put(original);
                count++;
            }


        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

            Logger.getLogger(reverseClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }
    }
    try {
        out.put(END);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(reverseClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Output Code
    @Override
    public void run() {

```
    while (isRunning) {

        String s = null;
        try {
            s = out.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(outputClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        try {

            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));

            try {
                if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(END)) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                writer.write(s + " ");


            }  finally {
                writer.flush();
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(outputClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show your code attempt to interrupt this.

Comment: What about a poison pill?

Comment: This is the producer and should never need to be explicitly shut down. It should run until the end of the stream and then just run off the end of the method.

Comment: This sounds exactly like a problem i just did for an Advanced Java class at my Uni...

Answer (score 2):

From the Javadoc:

> A `BlockingQueue` does not intrinsically support any kind of "close" or "shutdown" operation to indicate that no more items will be added. The needs and usage of such features tend to be implementation-dependent. For example, a common tactic is for producers to insert special end-of-stream or poison objects, that are interpreted accordingly when taken by consumers.

I suggest queuing the value `null` to indicate that the stream is over; the reader will need to check whether the value read is `null` and terminate if it is.

Comment: Shoving a null onto the queue as a suicide request is even more useful in languages without GC.  Since the null does not need to be deleted, a null can terminate an unknown number of threads waiting on a queue if the threads push the null back onto the queue before terminating themselves, and no need for a refcount on the null:)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are reading one word at a time, you can send a flag through the blocking queue. Sending the string literal "This queue is terminated" would be sufficient. Since you are reading only one word at a time, there is no way this string can be tested in your word reverse program.

Once this is received you can interrupt the word reverser. Then send the same literal to the writer. Once the writer receives the flag you can shut down the writer as well.

A.K.A "Poison Pill" as stated from Sotirios.

Example from reverser class:

```
/**
 * Called when being executed. Reverses a word by taking from intake and
 * places the reversed word into store
 */
@Override
public void run() {
    boolean isInterrupted = false;
    while (!isInterrupted) {
        try {
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(intake.take());

            //Exit condition
            if (str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(END_FLAG)) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }

            //If it is a word to be reversed, then reverse it
            if (oddWord % 2 == 1) {
                str = reverseWord(str);
            }

            //Put word in queue and increment counter
            store.put(str);
            ++oddWord;
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            isInterrupted = true;
        }
    }

    //Puts pill into queue when main body is done
    try {
        store.put(END_FLAG);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.err.printf("Error setting flag in store.%nWordReverser%n%s%n", ex);
    }
}
```

My `run()` method from the Writer Class:

```
    /**
     * Executes when being called in a thread
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean isInterrupted = false;

        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(output))) {

            //Continue writing until the thread is interrupted
            while (!isInterrupted) {
                CharSequence word = in.take();

                if (word.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(END_FLAG)) {
                    isInterrupted = true;
                } else {
                    writer.write(word + " ");
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException | IOException ex) {
            System.err.printf("Error writing to output file!%n%s%n", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am still having trouble even after I added the pill. I am going to edit my post and list all of my code.

Comment: After I edited the code to include the poison pill I am getting an output file with the correct output but now I receive a bunch of InterruptedExceptions and the program ever ends

Comment: The problem with the error messages is all of the logging that you are doing. While logging is good practice, you have to ask yourself what do you really want to happen when a thread becomes interrupted. Put some print statements to determine which threads are ending and which are stuck in the block and let me know. I will paste my run method for my program for you to compare to

Comment: I added a print statement  inside the reverse class. That is the one that keeps printing infinitely. So there is something wrong in that class but I am not sure what it is.

Comment: What exactly is printing forever? Is your thread catching the interrupted exception and logging it?

Comment: I added a println in the first interrupted exception in the reverse class that just says "reverse". It continues to print forever. I removed all the log statements

Comment: Got it. If `isRunning` is a flag, you are never changing that flag throughout your code. You should change the flag when you handle the `interruptedException`. If `isRunning` is not a flag i suggest making it one. For example, have your loop continue while it's running but as soon as you receive an `InterruptedException` set the flag to false.


TL;DR:
Your `while(isRunning)` loop never ends.

Comment: Yep that was the problem. It's working now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You're code is already halfway there ...

For the threads that block in the `take()` method, you need to:

1. Set the `isRunning` flag to `false`.
2. Call `Thread.interrupt()` on the thread object.

And you could avoid exposing the `isRunning` flag by setting it to `false` in the handlers for the `InterruptedException`.

For the thread that is blocking while reading from the `Scanner`, a `Thread.interrupt()` should result in a `InterruptedIOException`.  If not, then calling `close()` on the stream that the `Scanner` is using should be sufficient.  It requires a little bit of reorganization; i.e. constructing the `Scanner` with a `Reader` or `InputStream` instead of a `File` object.